# Sum column values in SELECT query with Codeigniter's ActiveRecord

Tags: php, codeigniter, select, sum, column-sum

Trying to get the sum of the values entered within a column (`af_am_msm`) from my table (`non_clinical_total_tests`). I want to display that total within an html table.

My error message is:

> A PHP Error was encountered - Severity: Notice - Message: Array to string conversion

My MODEL:

```
public function af_am_sum()
{
    $this->db->select_sum('af_am_msm');
    $query = $this->db->get('non_clinical_total_tests');
    return $query->result();
}
```

My CONTROLLER:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['af_am_total'] = $this->Page_model->af_am_sum();

    $data['pages'] = $this->Page_model->get_list();
    
    $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'district1', $data);
}
```

My VIEW:

```
<td><?php echo $af_am_total; ?></td>
```

Comment: Could please var_dump($af_am_total); And provide here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeigniter's `result()` function always returns an array of objects. In your view you echo it out as a string, hence the error. In order to avoid that you either produce result rows, [looping through the array](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-arrays), or:

like in your example, as you are expecting only one row (the sum of a column) you have the possibility to get this result row (without the need to loop through it) with `row()->the_name_of_your_column`. To simplify the output we can create an alias for the mysql sum, naming it as second parameter:

```
$this->db->select_sum('af_am_msm','my_sum');
$query = $this->db->get('non_clinical_total_tests');
return $query->row()->my_sum;
```

which echos in your view as pretended

Comment: Ok, and so this will also change my variable within my Controller, and View files from $af_am_total to $my_sum correct? (I'm a super codeigniter noob)

Comment: no, nothing else changes, its just a way to get the row value of the sum easier, in the line `return $query->row()->my_sum;` the variable $af_am_total will not change, as you continue to use in your controller `$data['af_am_total'] = $this->Page_model->af_am_sum();`, see also https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view, that explains how to get dynamic data into the view

Comment: Gotcha! Next I will research subtracting the sum of one column from another column, and dividing the sum of one column by the sum of another column!

Comment: @Vickel Here is our new room https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101945/room-for-u10-forward-and-vickel